# how to add class to a div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll

Previously I have used some jquery code to apply css style to a selected menu item. Here is the code I have used for this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-sentient a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the css

```
.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #207bc2 !important;
}
```

But now I have linked the menu items to some IDs with in one page. For eg. "portfolio" menu linked to "portfolio" ID. The "selected" class is not working now. So how can I make this code work for ID with in one page?

Comment: show ur markup or fiddle .

Comment: Show the code that fail and the HTML to go with it. Showing us the code that works doesn't help :)

Comment: Are you saying you want the page to scroll down to an identified page fragment  when you click on a menu item?

Comment: when i click on a menu item it scrolls down to the relative id. But the selected menu css is not changing. for eg. the selected menu item has a style of border bottom

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to make visible that a selected menu is active

```
$(document).on('click','#menu-sentient a', function() {
      var tag = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#menu-sentient a').each(function(index, value) {
           if($(this).attr('href') === tag) {
                $(this).addClass('selected');
           }
      });
});
```